# SimpleXML deserialization error in Android

Tags: java, android, simple-framework

I have problem with deserialization java-object. For deserialization I use [SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php).

```
@Root
public class A {
    @ElementList
    private ArrayList<B> b;

    getters, setters...
}  


public class B{
    @Element(name="C", required=false)
    private C c;

    getters, setters...
}  

public class C{
    private int id;
    private String name;

    getters, setters...
}
```

I receiving XML, which have next field:

```
<A>
   <B>
       <C i:nil="true" />
   </B>
</A>
```

Dalvink throws next exception: org.simpleframework.xml.core.AttributeException: Attribute 'nil' does not have a match in class B at line -1

Are there any ideas for solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you should add to your C class a property:

```
@Attribute(name = "i:nil")
boolean myProperty;
```

Comment: <C i:nil="true" /> means that C-object is null. But SimpleXML don't understand this. Also this XML-document  have field <D i:nil="true" />, D is String. I annotated @Element(required=false)String D. It works!

Comment: For a start this is not even valid XML, where is the namespace for the 'i' prefix declared? The above answer will work, but you could also read with Persister.read(A.class, sourceXml, false). This will ignore i:nill and no exception will be thrown.

Comment: I've tried this in latest version and it doesnt work. I've tried with prefix, without prefix, with namespace definitions. Nothing... Nothing won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Usually null content is presented with

```
xsi:nil="true"
```

attribute if that's what you're trying to do here.