# How can I avoid StAX API error on Android when I use JAXB?

Tags: java, android, jaxb

I've faced a strange error with `JAXB` on `Android`.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/21.0.2/dx --dex --output /Users/aaron/AndroidStudioProjects/client/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/stax-api-1.0-2-423956290996cba5c5243bbc25620fb74a9a3abd.jar /Users/aaron/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.xml.stream/stax-api/1.0-2/d6337b0de8b25e53e81b922352fbea9f9f57ba0b/stax-api-1.0-2.jar
  Error Code:
    1
  Output:
    trouble processing "javax/xml/stream/EventFilter.class":
    Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
    when not building a core library...
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like JAXB does not run on Android OOTB.

I see [here](http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android/) that people went great lengths to make it work, with some success. StAX is also not in the [SDK Level 21](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html).

See also:

[Is there a need in JAXB implementation for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734921/is-there-a-need-in-jaxb-implementation-for-android)