# Android Studio - XML Serialization and XML Validation against .xsd schema

Tags: android, xml, serialization, xsd, jaxb

I'm working with a Android App and XML.
By using Jaxb, I had java xml classes from a .xsd file.

I want to generate a xml file from these xml classes then validate against the .xsd file.

I found here an example:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

But I cannot use javax.xml.bind.Marshaller:

```
Error:(76, 27) error: cannot access XMLEventWriter
class file for javax.xml.stream.XMLEventWriter not found
```

Then I add javax.xml.stream lib:

```
java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I also posted a question about xml validation against xsd but till now I have not get any suggestion yet:
[Android XML validation using XSD ( both xerces and SchemaFactory) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31075984/android-xml-validation-using-xsd-both-xerces-and-schemafactory-error)

Any suggestion for me?
Thanks,

Comment: Last time I checked JAXB was not supported on Android. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461127/using-jaxb-with-google-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: 
XML Validation: xerces for android: https://code.google.com/p/xerces-for-android/source/checkout

XML Serialization: http://simple.sourceforge.net/

.xsd to java objects: Jaxb or Jibx

[Is there a need in JAXB implementation for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734921/is-there-a-need-in-jaxb-implementation-for-android)