# Repackaged JAXB on Android ends in Runtime Exception

Tags: android, xml, xsd, jaxb

I am developing an Android app which needs to render components dynamically according to an XML string. This XML string is based on an XSD and I am directly getting the XML from a server. I have used JAXB xjc to create an object model from the XSD. But now I want to be able to unmarshall and parse the complete XML with JAXB.
I went through a few posts here and in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461127/using-jaxb-with-google-android?answertab=active#tab-top), I found a solution where the last solution gives a [solution](http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android/comment-page-1/#comment-8424) to use a repackaged jaxb library. I followed the following steps:-

1.
Import the librarys:
activation.jar
additionnal.jar
ae-jaxb-2.2.5.jar
istack-commons-runtime.jar
jaxp-datatype.jar
txw2-20110809.jar

2. Replace my jaxb imports to ae.jaxb.
3. Added `RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.cachePackageAnnotation(RenderXml.class.getPackage(), new XmlSchemaMine(""));`
   to the onCreate method in my code. Here RenderXml is the name of my Activity.

I am still getting the following runtime errors :-

```
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRegistry
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotation(Native Method)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:260)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getClassAnnotation(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:109)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getClassAnnotation(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:59)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:330)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:461)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:299)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:142)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1164)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:146)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at ae.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:237)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at ae.javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:186)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at ae.javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:146)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at ae.javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:361)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at ae.javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:446)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at ae.javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:409)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at ae.javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:313)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at com.example.testuirenderxml.RenderXml.generateFirstMenu(RenderXml.java:79)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at com.example.testuirenderxml.RenderXml.onCreate(RenderXml.java:112)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry" on path: /data/app/com.example.testuirenderxml-2.apk
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-04 13:44:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     ... 35 more
```

I have the need to use jaxb because I have to generate the object model from an xsd which is updated regularly, is there any other way to create the object model and then parse the xml with the help of this object model so as to achieve what I want to?

Comment: I found the answer to this one but now I am getting a "No XMLSchema Annotation found" on the classes generated with JAXB xjc...do I need to regenerate the object model using the repackaged JAXB??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. I need to set the following in my onCreate method:-

```
RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.cachePackageAnnotation(LayoutT.class.getPackage(), new XmlSchemaMine("myNameSpace"));
```

where myNameSpace is the namespace I have for my XSD schema.

Comment: LayoutT is one of the classes in my Object Model generated with JAXB xjc...the first argument basically is the package name of the object model.