# How to use jaxb in android?

Tags: android, jaxb

is there any example project which includes jaxb. I tried it as in the normal java way but i received the a compile error of the dalvik vm.

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Does someone know how to solve this. I know that there are alternatives as simpleXml for android but its more work adapt my existing annotated classes with their annotation. An example or a good tutorial would be usefull. I did not find any good one.

Thanks

Comment: JAXB is not available in the Android OS. It is conceivable that somebody has a port of JAXB to Android, though it might have to have been refactored into a different package.

Answer (score 1):

this is sounds like a solution, see: http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android/

Answer (score 1):

See my answer here on using existing annotated JAXB classes with Android:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13077912/937715