# How to create XML from Java to save information?

Tags: android

I have an aplication that have to keep some information on the mobile i decided to
use generate xml every time and save it on a file of my project.

How can i create a XML and save it on a file of my project onClickEvent?

Comment: Is this any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461127/using-jaxb-with-google-android

Comment: JAXB is to heavy for the app, is there another option or maybe any idea how to keep information like a Data Base for the app

Comment: I know it's heavy, but if you read the answer, it's suggesting a simpler more lightweight XML parsing framework.

Comment: I just want that when app get close and open again save some information, is there another option?

Comment: Properties? http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/properties-file-in-android.html

Comment: ... are you talking about `SharedPreferences`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, look a this documentation: [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)
It explains pretty clearly how to write into a file.

Then, I recommend you to use "JSON" instead of "XML" because it's easier to use. Add your datas in a *JSONObject* and write your *JSONObject* in the file using `myJsonObject.toString()`.

For taking back, read your file content and parse it in a new *JSONObject* like that:
`JSONObject jsonDatas = new JSONObject(fileContent);`