# Standard equivalent for JAXB in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, xsd, jaxb

I am building an APP that uses XML requests and responses to communicate with a server via HTTP POST. Due to copyright restriction I cannot use SIMPLE XML to do (at least partially) what JAXB would normally do, and from all the information I have JAXB cannot be used on Android.

I did the job using XmlSerializer to build the request and XMLPullParser for parsing the response but I don`t like how the code looks like and I was not able to find any standard equivalent for JAXB in the Android SDK.

Is there any SDK component that I can use to transform the XSD schema files to Java classes and then use marshaller/unmarshaller to/from a XML file or I am stuck with using XmlSerializer/XMLPullParser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any SDK component that I can use to transform the XSD schema files to Java classes

No.

> I am stuck with using XmlSerializer/XMLPullParser?

You are welcome to use DOM or SAX instead of `XmlPullParser`, just as you can in classic Java.

There are also [several XML parsing libraries for Android](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/114), beyond just SimpleXML.

Answer (score 0):

See some previous posts on the topic:

- [Using JAXB with Google Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461127/using-jaxb-with-google-android)
- http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android/

I'd rather try [SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question -- and figured it out. Using [jackson-module-jaxb-annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-base) and [XmlToJson](https://github.com/smart-fun/XmlToJson) :

```
public static String jaxbObjectToXML(SomeClass object)
    {
        JaxbAnnotationModule module = new JaxbAnnotationModule();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);

        try {
            JsonToXml jsonToXml = new JsonToXml.Builder(
                    objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object)).build();
            return jsonToXml.toString();
        }catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.smart-fun:XmlToJson:1.5.1'
}
```