# Android Studio compiles project correctly, Gradlew does not with Databinding enabled

Tags: android, gradle, gradlew

After extensive google-ing and searching SO, I was not able to sufficiently find a solution to my problem.

#### The issue:

My project currently has Databinding v2 enabled and in my XML I do have 2 way data binding for view model properties.

Android Studio (v3.5.3) is able to compile the project fine and doesn't have any errors

Using the command line tool `./gradlew assemble<Release_type>` would result in

```
javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
```

#### The solution:

There were *some* hints on Google and SO regarding a change made from Java8 -> Java11 regarding this library.  I'm not entirely sure what that change was but Java11 doesn't include whatever library that is needed to compile the app. Upon further inspection, I realized I was running OpenJDK 11 and not OpenJDK 8.  According to various sources, the solution to this problem was to install `OpenJDK 8`.

Steps to success:

1. Uninstall OpenJDK 11 or greater
2. Run the following command

```
brew tap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk
brew cask install adoptopenjdk8
```

1. Now running `./gradlew assemble<release_type>` should work as expected.

#### What this solves

1. fastlane not being able to build
2. gradlew not able to build

#### Conclusion

Further google searching led me to a couple of articles related to OpenJDK 11.  Apparently, Android Studio doesn't support OpenJDK 11 yet but Android Studio 4.x will. 
 - [reference to SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56635255/where-to-put-jaxb-dependency-for-compiling-android-databinding-on-java-11)

I know this isn't an "actual" question but I leave this here in hopes that anyone else super frustrated (like myself) finds this potential solution useful and hopefully Google indexes this article :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Please see above for detailed *Solution*

#### TLDR

Steps to success:

Uninstall OpenJDK 11 or greater
Run the following command
brew tap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk
brew cask install adoptopenjdk8
Now running ./gradlew assemble should work as expected.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25149762)

Comment: @Nathan as stated in the answer, the details were inside the original question.  I have edited to reflect the exact same solution in the answer section. I did not use the "post answer button", I ticked the "QA style" when formulating the question. Thank you for your feedback.