# How to use JAXB with Retrofit instead of SimpleXml

Tags: android, xml, jaxb, retrofit2

According to the 2.4.0 update of Retrofit:

> New: Converter for JAXB replaces the now-deprecated converter for
>   Simple XML Framework.

I haven't found a single tutorial on how to implement this to replace my simple xml annotated pojos.

Can anyone share a quick guide on how to transition from simplexml to jaxb?

Answer (score 11):

I have been googling for this today, and eventually ended up on the [retrofit JAXB Github page](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/jaxb), where they politely tell us that JAXB does not work on Android:

> **Note that JAXB does not work on Android.**

Then I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13077912/6629569), where they provide a workaround for this problem.

Please note that I have not tested this myself as I am in a similar situation as you.
Trying to figure it all out when I stumbled upon your question.
Hope this helps! :)

Comment: if you do work on it please update the answer accordingly to mark it as correct for others (i stayed on simplexml as i noticed how huge jaxb is when i decompiled it)

Comment: I work on android and in gradle I added implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jaxb:latest.version'

Answer (score 2):

You can add like this

Add the dependency in the app-level Gradle.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.2' (Latest version)

 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(JaxbConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(httpClient.build())
                    .build();
```

But this will not work with your existing SimpleXmlFactory

Comment: JaxbConverterFactory is not to be found in the sub package of: import retrofit2.converter.* : I am using version 2.9.0

Comment: implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jaxb:2.7.2"